# if function or ? : operator in R

Tags: r, if-statement, operators

I'm looking for something like `cond ? a : b` or `if(cond, a, b)` in R (cond is some condition, returning vector of TRUE/FALSE). I know that in many cases I can use trick with the assignment:

```
tmp[cond] <- a
```

but this is not good for me as I don't want to change anything - I just need to get immediate R-value in expression. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ifelse(cond, a, b)
```

will do the trick if `a` and `b` are single values or both have the same length as `cond`. Otherwise, you have

```
if (cond) a else b
```

where `cond` must have length 1 and `a` and `b` can have any length.

Comment: Depending on the complexity of your condition, you may get faster code by doing logical comparisons, e.g.  `foo<-a*(bar>0) + b*(bar<0)` .

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: doesn't really work if a, b are strings, which are in my case